# TYPO3 Frontend access on localhost (BE access working fine)

Tags: xampp, typo3, frontend, vhosts

after successfully installing XAMP and then typo3 on my Mac, I set up a virtual host to avoid typing long URL when working on TYPO3.

I uncommented the http.conf line dealing with http-vhosts.conf so that I could set up virtual hosts, then I added my virtual host (called typo3dev) in httpd-vhosts.conf and I finally edited my hosts file accordingly.

So far so good, BUT now the issue that I'm having is that while pointing to the BE ( with `http://typo3dev/typo3/` ) works just fine (I am able to log in and have fun in there), I cannot see the Frontend:
When pointing my browser to `http://typo3dev/` , I get redirected to `http://typo3dev/get-started/` where I get a Page Not Found error

Looking at the server error logs in I get that

```
$[Thu Jun 21 12:39:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1/get-started
```

By the way, my hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       typo3dev
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf like that:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1"
    ServerName typo3dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help/ comment/ advice

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a RealURL/Apache configuration problem to me. Make sure that you [allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) `.htaccess` in your Apache configuration ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1"
    ServerName typo3dev

    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

... or configure the `RewriteRules` directly in the `VirtualHost` section.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1"
    ServerName typo3dev

    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/typo3/introductionpackage-4.7.1>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)$ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/.*$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to reload / restart `Apache` after making changes to the configuration.

Comment: Tried the first solution and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much! I now get smoothly redirected normally and the get-started works!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to me like you have installed the wrong package. Install only the source package because all other package is for demo. Also if you can avoid Apache. It's complicated and bloated. I can recommend lighttpd. It's much easier to configure especially with virtual domains.

Comment: I installed this package on purpose, as to be able to have a look at the demo site. As for apache, I find that xampp is a good way to start to play around with it, and as Apache is so widely used on the internet, any kind of experience with apache is also something that I am looking to. Complicated and bloated doesn't mean impossible nor interesting... But that you for the advice about lighttd, never heard about it and I'll take a look out of curiosity!

Comment: In my opinion, the demo package is a good way to get started with TYPO3, and some knowledge of the Apache webserver never hurts ;-)

Comment: @ricoleuthold: Then I'm not paid like you. Apache is bloated and complicated and it's damn slow.